# Java stream - purpose of having both anyMatch and noneMatch operations?

Tags: java, java-stream, matching, operations

The anyMatch operation will return true if it finds an element - the noneMatch operation will return false it if finds a matching element.

The anyMatch operation will return false if it finds no matching element - the noneMatch operation will return true if finds no matching element.

Therefore, instead of having both of these operations, could we not just do with one, or am I missing something? In essence, anyMatch returning false is a way of evaluating the truth of noneMatch's predicate.

Comment: Try analyzing the results of those methods on an empty stream

Comment: @Ferrybig: anyMatch returns false on an empty stream, noneMatch returns true on an empty stream. So OP's observation holds for an empty stream.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Same reason you have `a != b`, instead of only supporting `! (a == b)`:

- Easy of use.
- Clarity of purpose.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, we totally could.  There's at least a moderately reasonable reason for it, though: the `!` would go at the very beginning of a stream expression that could be chained many lines long, e.g. you'd have to write

```
 !collection.stream()
    .map(someMapFunction)
    .filter(someFilterFunction)
    .distinct()
    .sorted(myComparator)
    .map(someOtherMapFunction)
    .filter(someOtherFilterFunction)
    .anyMatch(somePredicate)
```

...and by the time you've reached the `anyMatch` when you're reading the code, the negation at the beginning is harder to remember.

(For what it's worth, the JDK generally seems to have a lot fewer redundant methods than other languages I could name.)